# Perform command multiple times using output in terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, delete-file

I'm trying to perform the following:

```
mdfind -name "application name"
```

As output I get:

```
/Applications/[Application]
~/Library/LaunchAgents/[Application]
...
```

The next step I'd like to do is:

```
sudo rm -rif "/Applications/[Application]"
sudo rm -rif "~/Library/LaunchAgents/[Application]"
...
```

So in this case I have to do `sudo rm -rif "/..."` multiple times. How can I automatically apply this deletion command repeatedly for all given directories?

**P.S.** Dividing the output into an array of strings and starting for-loop is not an option.

Comment: Please add the requirement that you want to prompt _once_ to present _all_ deletion candidates to the user, and then _batch_-delete, directly to your question. If this is not what you want, please clarify - _directly in your question_.

Comment: Be careful. `sudo rm -rif "~/Library/LaunchAgents/[Application]"` won't interpret ~ as your home directory.

Comment: @thatotherguy: That's a good point. Fortunately, the OP's sample code notwithstanding, `mdfind` always outputs _absolute, literal paths_ rather than `~`-based ones.

Comment: `sudo rm -rif ~/"..."` would behave as expected, though; by not quoting it, the shell expands the tilde before passing the resulting path to `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

As we now know, you first want to present the `mdfind` output to the user for confirmation, before performing actual deletion.

[Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599050/45375) gets you most of the way there, but - as of this writing - the way that the actual deletion is performed is both brittle and inefficient.<sup>[1]</sup>

Here's a robust alternative that makes only one assumption: that no paths have *embedded newlines* (which is exceedingly rare).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Determine the paths of the items to delete.
files=$(mdfind -name "application name")

# Present the paths to the user and ask for confirmation.
printf '%s\n' "$files"
read -p "OK to delete (y/N)? "
[[ $REPLY == [yY] ]] || { echo "Aborted." >&2; exit 2; }

# Perform batch deletion, passing (typically) *all* paths to `sudo rm -rf` *at once*.
printf '%s\n' "$files" | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 sudo rm -rf
```

Note that if there weren't a need to *display* the paths prior to deletion, you could use `mdfind -0 -name "application name"` to produce `NUL`-separated output to pass to `xargs -0` directly.

Since a shell variable cannot contain embedded `NUL`s, `\n`-separated output is produced first, for display, and then later transformed to `NUL`-separated output with `tr`, for `xargs -0`.

Using `NUL`-separated output consistently is the most robust option, as then even paths with *embedded* newlines are handled correctly.

In the case at hand, that would require caching the `mdfind` output in a temporary file first, which the above solution does *not* do for convenience and brevity, given that filenames with embedded newlines are extremely rare.

---

<sup>[1] The following points address *edge cases*, but it's important to know that they *can* be a problem:

* `read` without the `-r` option subjects the input to interpretation of `\` chars.

* `read` without setting `IFS` to the null string (`IFS= read ...`) trims leading and trailing whitespace.

Calling `rm` once for every filename is less efficient than passing all filenames *at once*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Put the output in a variable, and show it to the user. Then pipe the variable to a loop that executes the command:

```
files=$(mdfind -name "application name")
echo "$files"
read -p "OK to delete? " ok
if [[ $ok =~ ^y ]]
then 
    echo "$files" | while read -r filename; do
        sudo rm -rif "$filename"
    done
fi
```

Comment: First I need to show the user all the found directories, and only then delete them. It is not always possible to re-execute mdfind -name "application name", because there can be a lot of files

Comment: I didn't understand that in the question. I've updated the answer to show how to display the results first, then use them in the loop.